# Synchronize MeteorJS promise based migration

Tags: meteor

The notification always appears "Migrations: Finished migrating." before the real migration seed is finished. I chained all. I've checked all.
During migration, we use the async mechanism.

```
const { db } = MongoInternals.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver().mongo;
```

I've just found that [MeteorMigration](https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-migrations) does not support promise-based functional. As a solution we use [Meteor.wrapAsync](https://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-wrapAsync). But it does not help.

```
const wrapIntoMongoTransaction = Meteor.wrapAsync(function (func, callback) {
  wrapIntoMongoTransactionAsync(func).then(callback);
});
```

And then simply call.

Answer (score 1):

`Promise.await` from the package `meteor/promise` does it well. It makes asynchronous to synchronous code.

My code becomes looking the following way:

```
import { Promise } from 'meteor/promise';

function wrapIntoMongoTransaction(func) {
  Promise.await(wrapIntoMongoTransactionAsync(func));
}
```